# An issue with Image loading by the abolute URI

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have this function which returns the Uri.

```
public static Uri GetAppropriate(string imageName, string basePath = "/Assets/") {
        switch (DisplayInformationEx.Default.FriendlyResolution) {
            case FriendlyResolution.FullHD:
                return new Uri("ms-appx://" + basePath + imageName + ".screen-1080p.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            case FriendlyResolution.HD:
                return new Uri("ms-appx://" + basePath + imageName + ".screen-720p.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            case FriendlyResolution.WXGA:
                return new Uri("ms-appx://" + basePath + imageName + ".screen-wxga.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            case FriendlyResolution.WVGA:
                return new Uri("ms-appx://" + basePath + imageName + ".screen-wvga.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution type");
        }
    }
```

I have the image with the following path relative to the root of the application: //Assets/SquareBackground.screen-720p.jpg

I don't see the image when I make the following call:

```
private ImageSource backgroundImage;
    public ImageSource BackgroundImage {
        get { return backgroundImage; }
        set {
            backgroundImage = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>BackgroundImage);
        }
    }

protected override void OnViewAttached(object view, object context) {
        BackgroundImage = new BitmapImage(ImageChooser.GetAppropriate("SquareBackground")); 
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set the build action of images?

Comment: Change the build action to content, then change your Uri string to remove the "ms-appx://" prefix, then change the UriKind to Relative

Comment: Like Shawn is suggesting, the issue could be with your uri. You could follow this article step by step to get it working http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx.

It could be that the file build action isn't set to Content as it should be. Also, the specification for a package uri is appx:/// with three '/'

Comment: Also, make sure the code for OnViewAttached is called from the UI thread

Comment: 1. Build action is set to Content. 2. I want to get the appropriate image from everywhere pointing out only the name of the image. Because of that I don't want to use the relative uri, because that will lead to the necessity to point out the base path for the image. 3. I have already read that article. That article does not provide the way to reuse the same code for all images.

Comment: @EngineerSpock Have you tried "YourAppName;component/Assets/SquareBackground.screen-720p.jpg"?

Comment: return new Uri("../Assets/SquareBackground.screen-720p.jpg", UriKind.Relative); - works fine (when called from the folder "ViewModels".
return new Uri("/KingsSquare;component/Assets/SquareBackground.screen-720p.jpg", UriKind.Relative); - does not work (however this does not throw any exceptions).

Comment: You could also use the following relative path, which you can use from any file in your project, in whatever directory it is: new Uri("/Assets/SquareBackground.screen-720p.jpg", UriKind.Relative);

Comment: @sibbl It works))) Haha. You can add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Uri("/Assets/SquareBackground.screen-720p.jpg", UriKind.Relative);` is another way to let you use URIs relative to your project root